# Libgdx keyboard "enter"

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way to change the keyboard so it have a "enter" or "go" button in android like in chrome browser in android, when you are writting a url it shows a "go" button.

If so how to show it? and how to handle it?
I have researched but I ran out of words because my english is limited, and couldn't find anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX doesn't support this feature. If you want to implement it, you would have to fork LibGDX and modify AndroidOnscreenKeyboard, specifically the IME options that are placed on its TextView. Or you could submit a PR to add this as a configurable option.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/index.html) for android keyboard handling. it has everything you need including keyboard types.

And also look [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) for android specific code usage in libgdx.